# Error: Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'req.body' as it is undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm learning how to work with databases and I ran into the following problem that I can't solve:
I'm trying to change the data in the table, but I get an error every time
That's my Node.Js code:

```
app.post('/db/:userId', async (req, res)=> {
    const { userId } = req.params
    try {
        const conn = mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            database: 'testdb',
            password: ''
        })

        conn.connect( err=> {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
                return err
            } else {
                console.log('DATABASE ----- CONNECTED SUCCESSFULLY')
            }
        })

        const { name, scnmb, login, password, isLogged } = req.body;

        let create = `UPDATE user_info SET name = '${name}', scnmb = '${scnmb}', login = '${login}', password = ${password}, is_logged = '${isLogged}' WHERE user_info.id = ${userId};`
        conn.query(create, async (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(500).send("Error creating user");
            } else {
                res.json(result);
            }
        });



        conn.end(err=> {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
                return err
            } else {
                console.log('DATABASE ----- DISCONNECTED SUCCESSFULLY')
            }
        })

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.statusCode = 500
        res.json({ errcode: 500, errmsg: 'DataBase error', ...e})
    }

})
```

That's my request body(Im using Postman):

```
{
    "name": "Nikita",
    "scnmb": 5,
    "login": "+888",
    "password": 0,
    "isLogged": 1
}
```

And that's an error I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'req.body' as it is undefined
```

I'm sure this problem is simple, but I just don't have any experience to solve it.
Can you help me?

Comment: What does your entire `Express`  index.js look like? Also what exact URL are you POSTing to in Postman?

Comment: I've looked through my index.js and found that I forgot to use parser. Looks like you helped me. Thanks!